# How to add restriction to a Template Field so that it ll show/hide based on selected language version

Tags: content-editor, templates

I just want to show a template field to content editor when Poland language version is selected for the item. and want to not show that field if Romania language is selected.
Can someone pls suggest how to do it.

Comment: For this, we need to create a custom pipeline that overrides the Sitecore configuration for pulling the fields from the template and make that language-specific/dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to write some custom code snippet which allows you to hide the field on the basis of your condition.

This is an example of code that you can follow and modify it as per your needs.

```
public void Process(GetContentEditorFieldsArgs args)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
    if (args.Sections == null || args.Sections.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.Args = args;
    if (this.Args.Item != null && this.Args.Item.Paths.FullPath.StartsWith("/sitecore/content", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        //Get Id of the different fields to hide. Example:
        string excludedFields = "{AC2F70FF-F2C3-44AE-8F2E-6BFE44162DDC}";
        
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(excludedFields))
        {
            //determine the template sections that needs to be hidden and remove that from the list
            this.Args.Sections.RemoveAll(p => excludedFields.Contains(p.ID.ToString()));

            //determine the fields that needs to be hidden and remove those from the content editor list
            this.FilterFieldsFromSections(excludedFields);

        }
    }
}

private void FilterFieldsFromSections(string excludedFields)
{
    if (this.Args.Sections != null && this.Args.Sections.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    for (int fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < this.Args.Sections.Count; fieldIndex++)     {         Editor.Section currentSection = this.Args.Sections[fieldIndex];         if (currentSection != null &&             currentSection.Fields != null)         {             currentSection.Fields.RemoveAll(p => p.ItemField != null && excludedFields.Contains(p.ItemField.ID.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will need to patch the pipeline `getContentEditorFields` in order to trigger the code

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <getContentEditorFields>
        <processor type="YourNamespaceWithClassName, YourAssemblyName"/>
      </getContentEditorFields>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Note that your pipeline needs to get triggered last else it will get overriden by Sitecore Pipeline `getContentEditorFields`

Ref: https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/11/02/sitecore-hide-field-on-content-editor/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried this approach and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks @Sumit. It helps.